# Calculating percentile of normal distribution

Tags: python, normal-distribution

See this Wikipedia page: [Binomial proportion confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Agresti-Coull_Interval).

To get the Agresti-Coull Interval, one needs to calculate a percentile of the normal distribution, called $z$. How do I calculate the percentile? Is there a ready-made function that does this in Wolfram Mathematica and/or Python/NumPy/SciPy?

Comment: The integral expression in the "normal cdf I got exactly from Wiki" is unfortunately off by a factor of $1/\sqrt{\pi}$. There is no known exact formula for the normal cdf or its inverse using a finite number of terms involving standard functions ($\exp, \log, \sin \cos$ etc) but both the normal cdf and its inverse have been studied a lot and approximate formulas for both are programmed into many calculator, spreadsheets, not to mention statistical packages. I am not familiar with R but I would be astounded if it did not have what you are looking for built in already.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, it's fixed!  I am doing this using inverse tranformation, also "not allowed" to use too much built in.  It's for the sake of learning I suppose.

Comment: @Dilip: Not only is there no known exact formula, better yet, it is *known* that no such formula can exist!

Comment: @cardinal and Dilip: It's Box-Muller tranformation, I just edited the question, it's now on the first line.

Comment: Acklam's method (with root finding) is a very competitive approach to *approximating* the inverse cdf in double-precision floating point. The particular root-finding method he uses is not necessarily the best. As I recall, he makes a bit too strong of a point about that aspect.

Comment: @cardinal thanks for the idea, I'm asked to Box-Muller http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform It looks easy.  For STANDARD NORMAL case, I generate 2 uniform samples, U1, U2, then using Wiki formula, get my Z0 and Z1 as samples.  But, when I calculate it, I don't get

$$\Pr (Z0)=(U1)$$ 
$$\Pr (Z1)=(U2)$$

What's wrong?

Comment: I just plotted a histogram, the samples look normally distributed.  :)  But still don't understand the transformation!

Comment: @cardinal Yes, I am aware that it has been proven that no such formula can exist.  I should have worded my comment to reflect this fact.

Comment: The Box-Muller method _generates_ samples from a joint  distribution of independent standard normal random variables.  So histograms of the values generated will resemble standard normal distributions.  But the Box-Muller method is _not_ a method for computing values of $\Phi(x)$ except incidentally as in "I generated $10^4$ standard normal samples of which $8401$ has value $1$ or less, and so $\Phi(1) \approx 0.8401$, and $\Phi^{-1}(0.8401) \approx 1$.

Comment: I just chose $8401$ as an example of the kinds of numbers you might expect.  $\Phi(1) = 0.8413\ldots$ and so if you generate $10^4$ samples of a standard normal distribution, you should expect _close_ to $8413$ of the $10000$ samples to have value $\leq 1$.  You are implementing the Box-Muller method correctly, but are not understanding the results that you are getting and are not relating them to the cdf etc.

Comment: @DilipSarwate  
How should I extend this to normal with mean=3, var=2. I am trying to work through on the polar form on wiki. It says the polar form "maps them[samples] to two normally distributed samples".

Comment: From reading other sources, I don't think you can.  Box-Muller is specifically for standard normal.  Then, Wiki should be updated.

Comment: You can't, it says on the first line "generating pairs of independent, standard, normally distributed" lol.

Comment: @user1061210: To get from a pair of independent standard normals $(Z_1, Z_2)$ to an arbitrary bivariate normal distribution, all one needs to do is apply the correct linear transformation. This is a standard fact about jointly normally distributed random variables.

Comment: @cardinal, how about normal distribution mean=3, var=2?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out.  If anyone needs it, I'm glad to help.

Comment: The comments discuss variate generation; the text of the question appears to refer to computing the inverse CDF of a Normal distribution; additional comments provide no clarification.  There isn't any definite question to be answered here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *Mathematica* `$VersionNumber > 5` you can use

```
Quantile[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], 100 q]
```

for the `q`-th percentile.

Otherwise, you have to load the appropriate Statistics package first.

Comment: (I have version 7.) I have no problem loading the Statistics package. But what's the function in there called? Because I get the impression that this `Quantile` line will do the calculation manually instead of using a formula.

Comment: Evaluate it with symbolic parameters (i.e. don't assign values to `mu`, `sigma`, and `q`); you should get an expression involving the inverse error function.

Answer (score 22):

John Cook's page, [Distributions in Scipy](http://www.johndcook.com/distributions_scipy.html), is a good reference for this type of stuff:

```
In [15]: import scipy.stats

In [16]: scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.975)
Out[16]: 1.959963984540054
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. 
BTW, if you want to calculate the number of standard deviations around the mean which capture `p`% of probability, you can do it as follows: `sigmas_around_mean = lambda p: (norm.ppf(0.5 + p/2) - norm.ppf(0.5 - p/2))/2`

E.g. You should get `sigmas_around_mean(0.95) = 1.96`.
This is useful when you want to know how many stds around the mean capture, say, 50% of the probability mass.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you didn't ask about R, but in R you do it using ?qnorm

(It's actually the quantile, not the percentile, or so I believe)

```
> qnorm(.5)
[1] 0
> qnorm(.95)
[1] 1.644854
```

Comment: Quantile *vs.* percentile (it's merely a matter of terminology), http://j.mp/dsYz9z.

Comment: While we are in, in R Wald-adjusted CIs (e.g. Agresti-Coull) are available in the `PropCIs` package. Wilson's method is the default in `Hmisc::binconf` (as suggested by Agresti and Coull).

Answer (score 4):

In Python, you can use the [stats](http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Stats) module from the [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) package (look for `cdf()`, as in the following [example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)).

(It seems the [transcendantal](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/python/special.html) package also includes usual cumulative distributions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [inverse erf function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html), which is available in MatLab and Mathematica, for instance.

For the normal CDF, starting from

$$y=\Phi\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$$

We get

$$x=\sqrt{2}\ \text{erf}^{-1}\left(2y-1\right)$$

For the log-normal CDF, starting from

$$y=F_{x}(x;\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{2}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{-\log x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

We get

$$-\log \left(x\right)=\mu+\sigma\sqrt{2}\ \text{erfc}^{-1}\left(2y\right)$$

Comment: isn't this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: My idea was that if you have inverses for the erf and erfc functions, then the problem is solved.  MatLab, for instance, has such preprogrammed functions.

Comment: @Jean-VictorCôté Please, develop your ideas in your reply. Otherwise, it merely looks like a comment as suggested above.

Comment: The lognormal calculation doesn't look right.  After all, its inverse CDF should be *identical* to the inverse CDF for the normal apart for the use of $\log(x)$ instead of $x$.