# How to solve/compute for normal distribution and log-normal CDF inverse?

Tags: distributions, probability, self-study, monte-carlo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating percentile of normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/calculating-percentile-of-normal-distribution)

Edit: I think the hint is Box-Muller transformation.  Any ideas?

I am trying to find the inverse of normal CDF.

This is normal CDF I got exactly from Wiki,

$\Phi (x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{x}{{{e}^{-{{t}^{2}}/2}}}dt=\frac{1}{2}\left[ 1+erf\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \right]$.

This is the log-normal CDF,

${{F}_{x}}(x;\mu ,\sigma )=\frac{1}{2}erfc\left[ -\frac{\ln x-\mu }{\sigma \sqrt{2}} \right]=\Phi \left( \frac{\ln x-\mu }{\sigma } \right)$.

I was told there is an easy way using radian, but don't know how.  Any experts would know?
I have seen this: http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/

This is part of the inverse transformation I am doing.  R or Java will be used, an explicit formula would be helpful enough